# Shell script with whitespace in path executes differently depending on directory

Tags: bash, shell, path, whitespace

I have made a script to open Spotify with wine:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/home/jorgsk/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Spotify/"
cd "$DIR"
wine spotify.exe 2>/dev/null
```

I'm passing "$DIR" to cd with quotes because of the whitespace in "Program Files"; if I don't have the quotes "/home/jorgsk/.wine/drive_c/Programs" will be considered as the argument to cd, which obviously will result in an error message.

Spotify starts fine if I launch the above script from its local directory (/home/jorgsk/bin) with ./spotify. However, since I wish to launch it from wherever, I have /home/jorgsk/bin added to the $PATH variable in .bashrc. When I write "spotify" from for example my home directory, I get the error message

```
bash: /home/jorgsk/.wine/drive_c/Program: No such file or directory
```

which is the same error message I get if I don't include $DIR in quotes when launching tje script with ./spotify from the script's directory.

What is happening here?

Comment: When you type `which spotify` what are you getting back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the answer but I think I can give you a procedure that will identify the issue.

Add `set -x` to have the script echo the lines it is running.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 set -x
 DIR="/home/jorgsk/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Spotify/"
 cd "$DIR"
 wine spotify.exe 2>/dev/null
```

Also, name the script something other than `spotify`.  Although it doesn't immediately look like it would matter, who knows what complex behavior is happening once wine gets control?

Comment: Adding set -x did nothing, it just gave the same error as before. When I renamed the file to 'testme', Spotify launched and I got the output from the script as expected.

Comment: In other words, it works now! It seems that Wine must have a some kind of shortcut to spotify somewhere that I can't find. Yet mysteriously, "which spotify" gives "/home/jorgsk/bin/spotify"!

Comment: @Viktiglemma: Do `type -a spotify` instead of `which spotify`. It may tell you if there is an alias or function that is taking precedent over the executable in your `PATH`.

Comment: Indeed, there was an alias set for spotify... I have to admit that I set it myself and then later forgot about it. Regardless, I have learnt a lot, thanks for the answers.

Comment: Aha, that was what the "-x" was supposed to find. (It wasn't supposed to fix anything, it was just supposed to debug the script...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is happening - looks like it should work to me.

You say this is in your path but is that the version that is actually being called?

Try running: `which spotify` from your home directory. The which command tells you the path of the script that runs.